# AngularJS: передача данных между контроллерами

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Мне нужно передать из одного контроллера в другой информацию о выбранном option в теге select. Суть в том, что после выбора определенного значения появляется кнопка, которая открывает новую страницу (другой контроллер) и на этой новой странице должен уже быть выбран тот же option, как и на странице с которой я перешел.

Почему-то сервисы и фабрики на второй странице возвращают дефолтное значение(то, которое я указал при создании), а rootScope - undefined после изменений значий в этих переменных на первой.

Сервисы уже как только не писал, например сейчас:

```
  App.service('GeneralService', function () {
  this.userData = {yearSetCount: 0};

  this.setSetCount = function(setCount) {
        this.userData.yearSetCount = setCount;
  };

  this.getSetCount = function() {
        return this.userData.yearSetCount;
  };
 });
```

Мб дело в обновлении новой страницы? Перехожу на нее через событие windows.open

Comment: _Перехожу на нее через событие windows.open_ - открывает новую страницу никак не связанную с текущей, соответственно и сервисы там инициализируются отдельно

Comment: Спасибо. Но как тогда решить мою задачу?

Comment: не использовать window.open. это раз. Передавать данные напрямую в другое окно - это два